# problem with trying to create ssms add-in

Tags: .net, add-in, ssms

I'm trying to create an add-in for SSMS 2008 and/or 2008 R2 but I've run into a problem straight away.

I can get my add-in to work and on SSMS start-up get it to simply show a message box.

However, after downloading various code-samples, when trying to reference Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.ServiceCache I get a null reference exception:

```
Commands2 commands = (Commands2)ServiceCache.ExtensibilityModel.Commands;
```

I get this problem when using SSMS 2008 or SSMS 2008 R2.  I'm working on Visual Studio 2010.

It's a bit frustrating because I'm keen to learn more about SSMS add-ins but can't seem to get past the few samples out there.

Any advice/tips appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I had heard that SSMS was not extensible. Where did you find code examples?

Comment: @John Saunders: no no, SSMS definitely *IS* extensible! Check out http://www.ssmstoolspack.com/ for instance

Answer (score 5):

Karl, I don't know about your concrete problem here, but answering another question, I came across a bunch of articles and links on writing SSMS plug-ins - maybe one of them will be useful to you:

Some information can be found here:

- [The Black Art of Writing a SQL Server Management Studio Add-In](http://jcooney.net/post/2007/11/26/The-Black-Art-of-Writing-a-SQL-Server-Management-Studio-2005-Add-In.aspx)
- [Building a SQL Server Management Studio Add-In](http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/jonsayce/archive/2008/01/15/building-a-sql-server-management-studio-addin.aspx)
- [Extend Functionality in SQL Server 2005 Management Studio with Add-ins](http://aspalliance.com/1374_Extend_Functionality_in_SQL_Server_2005_Management_Studio_with_Addins.all)
- [SSMS Scripter - Internals, part 2 - plugging in](http://markegilbert.wordpress.com/2006/12/18/ssms-scripter-internals-part-2-of-3-%E2%80%9Cplugging-in%E2%80%9D/)

Comment: Thanks for the responses.  I've gone through the first three sites you mention there Marc - I haven't seen the SSMS Scripter site so I'll check that one out.

The specific code sample I've used was from the Extended SSMS Addin, found at http://extendedeventmanager.codeplex.com/releases/view/35325.

When I debug the sample the ServiceCache is always null and causes a null exception so I can't get past that point.

Answer (score 3):

ServiceCache is unreliable - from version to version it supports less and less and probable will go away at some point.

If you write SSMS Add-in, you can access internals by accessing VS ApplicationModel.
Something like that:

```
public void OnConnection(object application, ext_ConnectMode connectMode, object addInInst, ref Array custom)
        {
            _addInInstance = (AddIn)addInInst;
            _applicationObject = _addInInstance.DTE as DTE2;
```

_applicationObject has Commands and other interesting stuff.

**Please note**, that *application* argument of OnConnection has an incorrect object passed in. That's why you have to use this line to get the right object: **_applicationObject = _addInInstance.DTE as DTE2;**

Answer (score 1):

I've been struggling with this for a while.

I've got an add-in what work in sql 2008 - written in VS2008.

I upgraded the project to VS2010 and started working on getting the sql 2008 r2 add-in working - I could not get this working for love nor money.

I tried lots of different things;
* deleting and re-adding all the references.
* changing the target framework.
Not a sausage.

Nothing worked....
Until I went back to VS2008 - I made the changes. (see Jonathan Kehayias blog: https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/jonathan/sql-server-2012-extended-events-add-in-to-manage-2008r2-instances/)

Hurray for new versions!!

Answer (score 1):

Ok I find solution, the problem is between CLR2.0  and CLR 4.0

Source : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mshneer/archive/2010/03/19/com-shim-wizards-for-vs-2010.aspx

> Debugging add-ins targeting CLR 2.0 in
>   Visual Studio 2010
>
> I had some problems debugging add-ins
>   if those were loading in CLR 2.0. I
>   would press F5, Excel would start up
>   and my add-in would run but the
>   breakpoints were not getting hit. So I
>   wanted to share what's going on and
>   how to set up your environment in such
>   a way that F5 experience is not
>   completely broken.
>
> There is no magic in the way I usually
>   go about debugging the shared add-in -
>   either shimmed or unshimmed. I set a
>   breakpoint in the OnConnection method
>   in Connect.cs file, open project's
>   properties, go to the Debug section,
>   select the "Start External Program"
>   option and set the full path to my
>   Office application (e.g. "C:\Program
>   Files\Microsoft
>   Office\Office12\EXCEL.EXE"). Next I
>   right click on the project node in the
>   Solution Explorer and select "Set As
>   Startup Project". When I press F5 my
>   breakpoint is hit.
>
> In Visual Studio 2010 the breakpoint
>   is not hit if my add-in is loaded in
>   CLR 2.0. What's going on is that
>   debugger cannot attach to both CLR 4.0
>   and CLR 2.0 - it actually needs to
>   know before the fact whether it should
>   be using CLR 2.0 debugging engine or
>   CLR 4.0 debugging engine. When you
>   press F5 debugger tries to guess which
>   CLR will be started in the process.
>   The heuristic is based on reading the
>   EXE's .config file where required
>   runtime version is u8sually specified
>   and if the .config file is not found
>   than the debugger fires up the CLR 4.0
>   debugging engine. As we all know
>   Office application are not bound to
>   any particular version of the CLR so
>   the heuristic miserably fails.
>
> There are actually two ways of dealing
>   with it – one is to put an
>   .exe.config file alongside
>   the.exe itself e.g. when debugging
>   Excel 2007 I will create
>   Excel.exe.config and leave it in the
>   "C:\Program Files\Microsoft
>   Office\Office12" folder.
>
> But my preferred way of dealing with
>   this is different. In the Solution
>   Explorer I will right click on my
>   solution node and select "Add" ->
>   "Existing Project" and open
>   "C:\Program Files\Microsoft
>   Office\Office12\EXCEL.EXE". Next, I
>   will right click on this newly added
>   project and select "Set As Startup
>   Project". Next, I will open the
>   properties for this project and will
>   set the "Debugger Type" property to
>   "Managed (v2.0, v1.1, v1.0)". Now, I
>   will F5 and the breakpoint I've set in
>   OnConnection method will be hit.

Answer (score 0):

I've the same problem. I think that it's liked to the Framework

With Framework 3.5

> ServiceCache.ExtensibilityModel is not null

With Framework 4.0

> "ServiceCache.ExtensibilityModel" is
>   null

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thanks for this way, but if I have a project in Framework 3.5, VS2010 doesn't stop on my break point.
But if I change the Framework to 4, VS2010 stop on the breakpoint. But CreateToolWindow2 raise an exception, because isn't the same Framework !

I simplify the code as minimum :

```
    /// <summary>Implements the OnConnection method of the IDTExtensibility2 interface. Receives notification that the Add-in is being loaded.</summary>
    /// <param term='application'>Root object of the host application.</param>
    /// <param term='connectMode'>Describes how the Add-in is being loaded.</param>
    /// <param term='addInInst'>Object representing this Add-in.</param>
    /// <seealso class='IDTExtensibility2' />
    public void OnConnection(object application, ext_ConnectMode connectMode, object addInInst, ref Array custom)
    {            
       _addInInstance = (AddIn)addInInst;
       _applicationObject = (DTE2)_addInInstance.DTE;

       if (connectMode == ext_ConnectMode.ext_cm_Startup)//ext_ConnectMode.ext_cm_UISetup)
       {
       }        
    }

    /// <summary>Implements the OnStartupComplete method of the IDTExtensibility2 interface. Receives notification that the host application has completed loading.</summary>
    /// <param term='custom'>Array of parameters that are host application specific.</param>
    /// <seealso class='IDTExtensibility2' />
    public void OnStartupComplete(ref Array custom)
    {            
       Windows2 win2 = this._applicationObject.Windows as Windows2;

       if (win2 != null)
       {
           Assembly asm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
           AddIn addinobj;

           addinobj = this._applicationObject.AddIns.Item(1);

           object controlObject = null;

           Guid id = new Guid("4c410c93-d66b-495a-9de2-99d5bde4a3b9"); // this guid doesn't seem to matter?
           //Window                 
           Window windowTool = win2.CreateToolWindow2(addinobj,
                                                      asm.Location,
                                                      "MyAddinASupp.UserControl1",    "Zone de test", 
                                                      "{" + id.ToString() + "}",
                                                      ref controlObject);

          windowTool.Visible = true;
       }
    }
```