# Can we create SSMS 2008 R2 addin using Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, ssms-addin

I tried couple of times to create a SSMS 2008 R2 addin in VS2010, following below block but always I am unsuccessful. Any inputs?

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/shair/archive/2008/07/28/how-to-create-sql-server-management-studio-addin.aspx

Tnx.

Comment: There are some addins on codeplex you could download and have a look at the source code of (e.g. SQL Server internals viewer). I understand it is quite a painful process though and things often break between versions.

Comment: Have a look at this thread.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2935523/problem-with-trying-to-create-ssms-add-in

Answer (score 0):

Here is your answer and I can guarantee it is working
http://connectionbuttons.codeplex.com/discussions/351805#post834896

see my comment on compiling in VS2008 and not in VS 2010..that shldn't be a problem logically but not sure y it is a problem